# iphone app webview link action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

Is there a way to make the action of clicking a link in a html of a UIWebView to load another UIView and pass the value of the url to that view, instead of loading that html page in the same UIWebView. So basically, modify the default action of clicking a link in a UIWebView. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) do this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
  shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

  if ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
    // do something with [request URL]
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: is it a big deal to make it swift compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a bit more info using the same technique

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/iphone-sdk-tip-firing-custom-events-when-a-link-is-clicked-in-a-uiwebview/

Comment: Just a friendly tip, link-only answers are generally discouraged on Stack Exchange sites. The reasons for this are described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116301/131713) and at several other posts. Usually I just flag these and mods delete them, but I see you've been active recently, so I thought I'd give you a chance to update this (and possibly earn some rep!) first.